# Laravel View Make returns blank page

Tags: php, laravel, view

I'm having some problem returning a view in a specific function of my controller.

All my views are returning fine everywhere in my app, even in this controller. When I try to return any view, including test view that I can return somewhere else, I always end up on a blank page. My logs (PHP and Apache) are empty.

**Controller**

```
function firstfct($path){

 $obj = new Foo\Bar($this);
 $obj->Insert($path);

 }

function ReturnsBlank(){

        //Fetching some variables that I was able to dump

       return \View::make('test'); //Blank
       //return var_dump('FooBar'); // Returns "FooBar"
}
```

**The Foo/bar file**

```
class SomeClass{

protected $listener;

public function __construct($listener)
{

$this->listener = $listener;

}

function Insert($path){ 

 //Some stuff that it is working well
 return $this->listener->ReturnsBlank();


 }
 }
```

**test.blade.php**

```
<pre>   
    Done!
</pre>
<hr/>
```

Comment: Is the problem specific to this controller or everywhere? if you just echo something in the controller, no View, you see that?

Comment: @alou It's specific to this function in this controller for some reason. I can't even debug because I have no log. I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: Wistar - are you calling this function from ANOTHER function in your controller? Or is this the 'main' function in your controller?

Comment: In App/Config/App.php is 'debug' => true ? I would think not... if you turn this on, you'll see all the errors. Also, are you namespacing the controller? if so, you should reference the root like \View::make('some.view')->with('data', data)...

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Made the edit. I call it from somewhere else

Comment: @alou Yes it's true, I checked and I can debug anywhere else in app. Actually I use `\View`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is your firstfct controller is not actually 'returning' anything to Laravel. The view is 'returned' to the function firstfct - but you need to pass it on

Change

```
function firstfct($path){

 $obj = new Foo\Bar($this);
 $obj->Insert($path);

 }
```

to

```
function firstfct($path){

 $obj = new Foo\Bar($this);
 return $obj->Insert($path);

 }
```